# Adding The Sum Of Nested List In Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket, nested-lists

I'm using scheme. I'm having no problems in finding the sum of a certain list but I'm quite having trouble in adding the sum when a list has a list in it or AKA Nested List.

```
(define (my-summation li)
(if (null? li)
  0
  ((if (list? (car li)) (my-summation (car li))
  (+ (car li) (my-summation (cdr li)))))))
```

This was my input and this was the result of the error. Scheme is my weakness since it involves recursion but I can't seem to find the problem.

```
> (my-summation '(6 3 -2 5 '(4 2 -3) 4 )) 
function call: expected a function after the open parenthesis, but received -3
```

Comment: Note that `'(6 3 -2 5 '(4 2 -3) 4 )` is the list `(6 3 -2 5 (quote (4 2 -3)) 4)`.  You don't need to nest your quotes.  You probably wanted the list `'(6 3 -2 5 (4 2 -3) 4)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its in the parentheses, you have an extra set around the `if`. Also you don't need to quote a list when it is in a quoted list. And the `(list? (car li))` case was incorrect, it should sum the element and the rest of the list.

```
(define (my-summation li)
  (if (null? li)
      0
      (if (list? (car li))
          (+ (my-summation (car li)) (my-summation (cdr li)))
          (+ (car li) (my-summation (cdr li))))))

(my-summation '(6 3 -2 5 (4 2 -3) 4))
```

Results in a sum of `19`.

Comment: I didn't notice that. Sorry, but I somehow it's not reading the last digit after the parenthesis though. Not sure why. Am I doing something else wrong?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution:

```
(define (sum-list xs)
  (define (loop sum-so-far xs)
    (cond
      [(null? xs)        sum-so-far]                              ; no-more-elements
      [(pair? (car xs))  (loop (+ sum-so-far (sum-list (car xs))) ; the first element is a sublist
                               (cdr xs))]                         ;   so sum-list computes its sum 
      [else              (loop (+ sum-so-far (car xs))            ; the first element is a number
                               (cdr xs))]))                        ;  so it is added directly
  (loop 0 xs))

(sum-list '(6 3 -2 5 (4 2 -3) 4)) ; note: no quote in the middle

; ==> 19
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative solution but is there something wrong with my code? I hope I could get some criticism.

Comment: @user3255372  Nothing wrong - more a matter of taste. I find nested ifs hard to read. The `cond` expression makes it clear that you have three cases.